# How do I get the 2nd and 4th character from a string

Tags: regex, string, bash, substring, cut

I have a script that emails database information for a website to me. However I need to grab the 2nd and 4th character of the domain name as two variables in my bash script.

Currently I have the following for getting the second level domain name.

```
DOMAINNAME=`echo ${NEW_DOMAIN_NAME} | grep -oE '/[^/]+' | cut -c6- | rev | cut -c4- | rev`
```

But now I need to get the 2nd and fourth character of that string $DOMAINNAME

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you give an example of the _characters_?  It seems that you want something other than characters.

Comment: It would be fairly easy. As easy as `echo $DOMAINNAME |cut -d4,6` This will 4rth 'AND' 6th but sure you are looking for something else.. Are you?

Comment: I just need the 2nd and 4th character of whatever string $DOMAINAME holds. Chris below gave me the right answer I need, the cut one seemed to be problematic when I tried implementing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

with bash variables, you can do this:

```
DOMAINNAME=abcdef
CHAR2=${DOMAINNAME:1:1}
CHAR4=${DOMAINNAME:3:1}
echo "char2=$CHAR2, char4=$CHAR4"
```

gives:

```
char2=b, char4=d
```

**explanation**

the meaning of this: `${DOMAINNAME:3:1}`means: take substring starting from the character at pos 3 (0-based, so the 4th character), and length = 1 character.